# Capybara/Selenium gets a Net::ReadTimeout randomly on location.reload()

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, selenium, capybara, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Capybara, the selenium-webdriver gem, and chromedriver in order to drive my javascript enabled tests.

The problem is that about 50% of our builds fail due to a `Net::ReadTimeout` error. At first this was manifesting as a 'could not find element' error, but after I upped Capybara's default max wait time to 30 seconds, I started seeing the timeout.

I examined the screenshots of when the timeout happens, it's stuck on a 'Successfully logged in' modal that we show briefly before using the Javascript function, `location.reload()`, to reload the page.

I've ran the test locally and can sometimes reproduce it, also randomly. Sometimes it zips by this modal and does the reload so fast you can barely see it, and other times it just hangs forever.

I don't feel like it's an asset compilation issue, since the site has already loaded at that point in order for the user to access the login form.

Wondering if anyone has seen this before and knows a solution.

The specific code:

```
    visit login_path

    page.within '#sign-in-pane__body' do
      fill_in 'Email', with: user.email
      click_button 'Submit'
    end

    expect(page).to have_content 'Enter Password'

    page.within '#sign-in-pane__body' do
      fill_in 'Password', with: user.password
      click_button 'Submit'
    end

    expect(page).to have_text 'Home page landing text'
```

The hang up happens between `click_button 'Submit'` and expecting the home page text.

The flow of the logic causing the timeout is the user submits the login form, we wait for the server to render a `.js.erb` template that triggers a JS event upon successful login. When that trigger happens we show a modal saying that login was successful, then execute a `location.reload()`.

Comment: Do you have anything in your app (rack-attack, etc) that throttles requests? If not, check your test.log for info about whether the request was actually made and what the app was doing.  Also, what do you have `Capybara.server` set to?

Comment: I know I said yesterday I was able to reproduce locally, but having a hard time doing that today to check the log. No request throttling. I'm not manually setting the server to anything, so it's whatever the default is.

Comment: If you haven't set `Capybara.server` to anything it defaults to Webrick which can have issues with multiple simultaneous requests. Try setting `Capybara.server = :puma` and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I've tried out puma, which didn't seem to work, so I switched back to the default for the time being. What's interesting is that after several runs I've actually started seeing the Net::ReadTimeout in other places. It's very rare but sometimes happens just doing a `visit path`.

Comment: If I watch the specs run, I can see it hitting the point where it times out, and the loading indicator in chrome continuously spins, but nothing ever happens. Looking through the test log it looks like that to Rails, everything is normal. It sees itself responding and rendering pages normally. In the case of the JS issue I saw earlier, it renders the templates I would expect it to.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole I ended up manually creating an http client and setting a longer read timeout. Seems to have resolved it. I'll post an answer here with details.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It turned out this wasn't exclusive to doing a `location.reload()` in JS. It sometimes happened just visiting a page.

The solution for me was to create an HTTP client for the selenium driver and specify a longer timeout:

```
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
  client.read_timeout = 120

  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, {browser: :chrome, http_client: client})
end
```

Comment: This did not work for me and I continued to get the error

Comment: this works for me. fixed the timeout error on certain tests on aws c9

Answer (score 2):

Solved similar problem by using my own version of visit method:

```
 def safe_visit(url)
  max_retries = 3
  times_retried = 0
  begin
    visit url
  rescue Net::ReadTimeout => error
    if times_retried < max_retries
      times_retried += 1
      puts "Failed to visit #{url}, retry #{times_retried}/#{max_retries}"
      retry
    else
      puts error.message
      puts error.backtrace.inspect
      exit(1)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I think there's a bug in that code. Replace `current_url` with `url`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you need to do if you need to configure it for headless chrome

```
Capybara.register_driver :headless_chrome do |app|
  client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
  client.timeout = 120 # instead of the default 60
  options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
  options.headless!

  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, {
    browser: :chrome,
    http_client: client,
    options: options
  })
end

Capybara.default_driver = :headless_chrome
Capybara.javascript_driver = :headless_chrome
```

Passing headless argument in capabilities was not working for me.

```
capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
   chromeOptions: { args: %w[headless disable-gpu] }
)
```

Here is [more details](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/issues/2065#issuecomment-402526800) about why headless in capabilities was not working.

Comment: `headless!` throws a deprication warning now:  WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION] [:headless] `Options#headless!` is deprecated. Use `Options#add_argument('--headless=new')` instead.